# Brute Force with Hydra Ignore timeout and 4 billion limit

Tags: brute-force, hydra

We are doing an assignment where we are hacking eachothers websites or servers in school. I know the default username and know the default password is 32 characters long to ssh in.

While I know I wont crack a password that long in the time given I still want to attempt it for testing purposes. Hydra keeps on timing out or gives me the error not being able to do more than 4 billion guesses. Any way to bypass this just for experimental purposes and run it for a bit.

Having a guesstimate on the time it would take would be interesting to know to put in my report as well.

Comment: "a bit" :-)
I think you could probably make a custom script to do this, but unless you have a good clue about what their password is (i.e: passphrase) you won't easily guess it if you're doing a normal bruteforce over the entire keyspace.

Comment: Do you know how long it takes to try ten passwords?  Then you can multiply that out appropriately.